# Error while trying to load mapfragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-fragmentactivity

I just started using fragments on android and im having really bad time trying to start 
a map fragment (on a full screen) inside a fragment activity - I have tried e-v-e-r-y-t-h-i-n-g - 
 1. Myproject>Android tools>Add support library
 2. Adding the support and google play services as jar \ libs
 3. restarting ecipse
nothing seem to help...
the attached is my logcat output -

```
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.telofun/com.telofun.FragmentMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at com.telofun.FragmentMap.onCreate(FragmentMap.java:23)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    ... 11 more
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    ... 20 more
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.telofun-1.apk]
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-27 20:49:09.421: E/AndroidRuntime(11714):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
```

that is the layout  -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code -

```
package com.telofun;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

public class FragmentMap extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    Marker marker = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
                                                    // not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Make sure you have referenced google play services library project properly.

Answer (score 1):

As Raghunandan says  change the MapFragment for SupportMapFragment. But I think it is not that simple. I had the same error and tried like 6 tutorials, and read all the documentation from google. And finnally I've got it running and displaying the map. This is how it works for me.

1.Remove the libraries google-play-services and android support-v4 from both your eclipse and your PC. 2.Download again it from de sdk-manager. 3.Follow the instructions [here] (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code) go to Sample Code and do as it says. Check specially this Existing Android Code Into Workspace , do not import the libraries as projects, they won't work. 4.Change all your MapFragment for SupportMapFragment, don't foget to extend your Actvity to FragmentActivity (that was my fail). 5.Disable (if it is enabled) the build automatically option from your project. 6.Clean the project. 5.Enable the build automatically option.
It should work.

If it works but the maps don't show you should go to the API consolo and turn on the Google Android Maps v2 and turn off the Google Maps v2.

Hope you can fix it!

Comment: +1'nd for trying...@Raghunandan answers fixed it though...tnx anyway bro